# Combining Numpy Arrays in Blockwise Form

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have three Numpy matrices

`a = np.matrix('1 2; 3 4')`

`b = np.matrix('5 6 7; 8 9 10')`

`c = np.matrix('1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9')`

and I would like to make the following block matrix:

`M = [a b ; 0 c]`,

where `0` stands for a matrix of zeros with the relevant dimensions.

Comment: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html

Comment: TIL: string syntax for `np.matrix` (but not `np.array`)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An easy way to create a block matrix is [`numpy.bmat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bmat.html) (as pointed out by @inquisitiveIdiot). Judging by the block matrix you're looking to create, you need a 3x2 matrix of zeros:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> z = np.zeros( (3, 2) )
```

You can then create a block matrix by passing a 2x2 array of the blocks to `numpy.bmat`:

```
>>> M = np.bmat( [[a, b], [z, c]] )
>>> M
matrix([[  1.,   2.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
        [  3.,   4.,   8.,   9.,  10.],
        [  0.,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  0.,   0.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  0.,   0.,   7.,   8.,   9.]])
```

Another (IMO more complicated) method is to use [`numpy.hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) and [`numpy.vstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html).

```
>>> M = np.vstack( (np.hstack((a, b)), np.hstack((z, c))) )
>>> M
matrix([[  1.,   2.,   5.,   6.,   7.],
        [  3.,   4.,   8.,   9.,  10.],
        [  0.,   0.,   1.,   2.,   3.],
        [  0.,   0.,   4.,   5.,   6.],
        [  0.,   0.,   7.,   8.,   9.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, that works; will go through documentation better next time.

Comment: Watch out for the fact that this returns a `np.matrix` and not a `np.array`

Answer (score 0):

My method to generate and join block-wise matrix:

```
def blockwise(matrix, block=(3, 3)):
    shape = (int(matrix.shape[0] / block[0]), int(matrix.shape[1] / block[1])) + block
    strides = (matrix.strides[0] * block[0], matrix.strides[1] * block[1]) + matrix.strides
    return as_strided(matrix, shape=shape, strides=strides)

def block_join(blocks):
    return np.vstack(map(np.hstack, blocks))

arr = np.arange(36).reshape((6, 6))
blocks = blockwise(arr, (3, 3))
print(blocks)
re_join = block_join(blocks)
print(re_join)
```

then the output is as following:

```
>>>>[[[[ 0  1  2]
   [ 6  7  8]
   [12 13 14]]

  [[ 3  4  5]
   [ 9 10 11]
   [15 16 17]]]


 [[[18 19 20]
   [24 25 26]
   [30 31 32]]

  [[21 22 23]
   [27 28 29]
   [33 34 35]]]]
[[ 0  1  2  3  4  5]
 [ 6  7  8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15 16 17]
 [18 19 20 21 22 23]
 [24 25 26 27 28 29]
 [30 31 32 33 34 35]]
```